# How do I use Search-AzGraph to report on operating system form microsoft.web/serverfarms

Tags: azure, powershell

Assuming I am using a bicep file to deploy an app service:

```
param tags object
param name string
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param skuName string = 'F1' 

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' = {
    name: name
    location: location
    properties:{
        
    }
    tags: tags
    sku: {
        name: skuName
    }
    kind:'windows'
}

output resourceId string = appServicePlan.id
```

I want to report on all my resources that are in a resource group, and for the app service plan resources (microsoft.web/serverfarms) I want to report on the operating system.

So I have a powershell command that look like this:

```
Search-AzGraph -query "where resourceGroup in ($resourceGroupFilter)  | project name, type, kind, location, resourceGroup, sku, OS = tostring(properties.kind) | order by name asc"
```

For the value of kind is always 'functionApp', it is not 'Windows' or 'Linux'.  How can I change the query to report on the operating system if the resource type is an app service plan?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `kind` property you need to focus on `reserved` property. This property determines which operating system does your app service plan is running on.

- If reserved property = true --> then it's a Linux app service plan.
- If reserved Property = false --> then it's an Windows based app
  service plan.

[image]

Refer to this [AppServicePlan properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/serverfarms?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#appserviceplanproperties) section in arm template schema for app service plan.

**Here is the sample query to pull the Linux app service plan under the subscription**:

[image]

**Note**: Reserved property lies under Properties of App service plan. If you want to apply a filter on it. In AzGraph queries you need apply filter as shown in the sample using `properties.reserved == "true"`